# Create a Promise object based on the current platform

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, promise

I am using **Apache Cordova** and I've run into a multi-platform issue in regards to the `Promise` object.

Currently, I have to instantiate a promise like this:

```
var promise = new Promise(...) {
    //Implementation
}
```

This is fine, however if the app is running on the **Windows** platform, I have to use `WinJS` instead. Like this:

```
var promise = new WinJS.Promise(...) {
    //Implementation
}
```

This results in the following code:

```
var promise;

if (cordova.platformId == "windows") {
    promise = new WinJS.Promise(...) {
        //Implementation
    }
} 
else {
    promise = new Promise(...) {
        //Exactly the same implementation as above
    }
}
```

The main issue here is that I am **duplicating the implementation** inside each promise, resulting in two blocks of code which is exactly the same. Therefore it's harder to maintain.

Is there a way I can instantiate the correct `Promise` based on the current platform without having to duplicate the code twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Promise` doesn't exist, you could just assign it to `WinJS.Promise` and then use `Promise` like you normally would.

Like:

```
if (typeof Promise === 'undefined' && cordova.platformId === 'windows') {
  Promise = WinJS.Promise; // global assignment
}

// At this point you can use new Promise() as usual
```

Answer (score 3):

As you develop in JS/Angular, why don't you use the Angular Promise?

I mean $q, an implementation of promises/deferred objects.

See [Doc for $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)